# SONAR Integrated with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ant, sonarqube

Am working on sonar integrated with eclipse using ant

But when i go "right click project-->configure-->associate with sonar" nothing happens!!

My ant version is 1.7.1

Eclipse is Helios(3.6)

sonar version is 3.4.1

Welcome all your favours..........

Comment: Did you configure your sonar instance in the preferences?

Comment: What version of the sonar eclipse plugin are you using?

Comment: @SpaceTrucker : I Configured in 'Preferences" with admin/admin as credentials which shows 'Successfully connected'.\ but on Finish, it shows Error- INSTANCE

Comment: @Pushy sonar eclipse plugin version --> 3.0.0.20130108-1647-RELEASE

Answer (score 3):

Sonar Eclipse has nothing to do with Ant, it's really independendent.

You should follow the different steps listed in the [documentation page](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Using+Sonar+in+Eclipse). Most notably, you need to have a Sonar server up and running somewhere (on your local computer or elsewhere) and you must make sure that you already launched an analysis of your project, which you can browse on Sonar Web application. If not, you'll never be able to associate your project in Eclipse.

Once you have a first analysis of your project on the Sonar server, then you need to configure the URL of your server in the Eclipse settings. Only after this, you'll be able to associate your project with Sonar.

Comment: I can see my eclipse project on the sonar web page. but what u mean by 'launching project analysis'.. could u pls elaborate..

Answer (score 0):

This might have to do with your plugin version. As described in the [docs](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+Sonar+in+Eclipse) Version 3.0 is only compatible with Eclipse 3.7 and up.

I would suggest you either upgrade your eclipse or you downgrade your plugin.